# SQL Select Statement showing an extra field

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Using C# and SQL Server, I'm trying to show the Name of a specific ID from a different table into a separate listbox, **using this code:**

```
              Con.Open();
                cmd2.CommandText = "select Name from [Client Table] where [Client Table].ClientID in (select [Outlet table].ClientID from [Outlet table] where City='London')";
                dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr2.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr2.Read())
                    {
                        listBox4.Items.Add(dr2[0].ToString());
                    }
                }
                Con.Close();
```

**which shows this result in the listbox:**

```
   Client Name:
   ____________
   SANYO
   SAMSUNG
   SANYO
```

**However, when I select the fields through this code:**

```
              Con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "select OutletID, ClientID, City from [Outlet Table] where City='London'";
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        listBox2.Items.Add(dr[1].ToString());
                        listBox3.Items.Add(dr[2].ToString());
                    }
                }
                Con.Close();
```

**it shows me a result of:**

```
   Outlet ID:                 Client ID:                 City:   
   ____________               ____________              ____________  
   1                          1                         London
   8                          2                         London
```

**When combined, it looks like this:**

```
   Outlet ID:                 Client ID:                 City:               Client Name:
   ____________               ____________              ____________         ___________
   1                          1                         London               SANYO
   8                          2                         London               SAMSUNG
                                                                            SANYO
```

My first Select statement seems to be showing an extra line for some reason, even though it should only have 2 rows. The second select statement seems to be the correct one, but I can't seem to find what's wrong in my first select statement.

Comment: My first Select statement seems to be showing an extra line for some reason >> didnt get it. can you pls explain it again?

Comment: You are selecting from different tables, why do you assume they have the same number of records?

Comment: check your data for duplicated names, otherwise use distinct in first query

Comment: No I have no duplicate names, and each of the clients have different names.

Comment: @RhymbertAranasII you do have two clients with name `SANYO`. The very first select gives you this result.

Comment: I realize you may only be a beginner, but mixing "SqlCommand" with "ListBox" code is brutal on the eyes.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

You would appear to have a `clientId` that appears twice in the table.

This is easy enough to verify:

```
select clientId
from [Outlet Table]
where City = 'London'
group by clientId
having count(*) > 1;
```

In the first query, you are only selecting the `name`, so you are not seeing the other columns.

Comment: The reason why I made a separate query for the Client name is because I'm trying to get name value of the [Outlet Table].[ClientID] from the foreign key ClientID, it seems that it always adds an extra columm when I use the first code.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server, a subquery inside a query gets executed first, which in your case, your subquery returns three client names. Have you tried updating your subquery?

We can try it like this:

```
 SELECT OutletId,[Outlet table].ClientID, City
    FROM [Outlet table] 
    WHERE City='London' AND [Outlet table].ClientId IN 
    (
       SELECT [Client Table].ClientID 
       FROM [Client Table] 
       WHERE [Outlet table].ClientId = [Client Table].ClientID
    )
```

I Hope this helps =)